# strict htaccess for digitalus

Tags: zend-framework, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

after installing digitalus i created the following rule (.htaccess ) file in the root directory

```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ecn.local
    DocumentRoot /home/speshu/Development/ecn
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV tinsae
    <Directory /home/speshu/Development/ecn>
            DirectoryIndex index.php
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

and put 127.0.0.1    ecn.local in /etc/hosts

but when i type http://ecn.local/scripts or http://etc.local/library or some existing folder in the document root rather than displaying a not found (404 message ) it lists all the folders in there how can i restrict this

in may earlier projects i remember having such restrictions on zend-framework what is the problem with digitalus since it's built on the same framework ..............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with out modifying in the `digitalus`

just add `Options -Indexes` to your wanted folder and it will hide the files (aka 'forbidden message ') like :

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /library on this server.
```

for example , if you need to hide the library folder 
just create `.htaccess` file inside of it and write down `Options -Indexes` 
and it will do the job :)

Comment: but u want to display not found 404 from my application with all the style and so.........

Comment: this way won't display folder's content but all styles and JavaScript would still accessible

Comment: what i mean is i just want to display the error in the main content area of the page ,jus like a standard zend-app